# API Яндекс.Погода. Не работает в доменной зоне .com?

Tags: яндекс-погода

Мой код:

```
$city_id = 8212;
$data_file = "http://export.yandex.ru/weather-ng/forecasts/".$city_id.".xml";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($data_file);

$temp = $xml -> fact -> temperature;
if ($temp > 0) {
    $temp = '+' . $temp;
}
```

Вставляю значение $temp:

```
<div class = "cloud"><p><?=$temp?></p></div>
```

Не работает на анг. версии сайта который расположен в доменной зоне .com (не показывает температуру)
Этот же сайт , русс версия, в доменной зоне .ru , этот же код - всё работает.

Comment: А ошибки какие-то есть? В браузере.

Comment: ни каких ошибок . делаю var_dump($xml)  - возвращает false . 
И еще одно уточнение. рус . версия лежит на русском хостинге, а анг. версия на испанском хостинге. Может дело в хостинге ? Т.к. я уже и api yahoo попробовал и даже он не работает на испанском хостинге, а на русском оба api работают.

Comment: А можете дать ссылку на английский сайт? там где должна быть погода.

Comment: http://avicenamed.com/

Comment: Попробуйте прям с сервера вызвать wget или чем-еще можно выполнить get запрос с вашего сервера, если не получиться, значит проблема где-то в сервере и его размещении.